# Problem with math symbols unicode-math

Tags: symbols, luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm begginer with `lualatex`, `fontspec` and `unicode-math` packages. I try load differents fonts for text and for math operators. But some math symbols not appears. For example, I try this (just to show differences fonts):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{luaotfload,lualatex-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Niconne-Regular}[
              Path = /home/juanuni/.fonts/ ,
                              ]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
 \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin}]{Diavlo_BOOK_II_37}

\begin{document}
This is a proof $\sin x^2$ $\sum$ $\delta$
\end{document}
```

To get:

[image]

As you can see, the commands `\sum` and `\delta` have no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably not necessary to load the `lualatex-math` and `luaotfload` packages explicitly.

Comment: You are right, is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare a math font:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Zapfino}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin}]{TeX Gyre Heros}

\begin{document}
This is a proof $\sin x^2$ $\sum$ $\delta$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how I know math fonts? I have problems with Cambria Math

Comment: It may be a good idea to add the option `Scale=MatchLowecase` to the `\setmathfont` instructions.

Comment: @juanuni ......... to have equal x-heights across text and math fonts

Comment: Thanks. But now I have a problem with `Cambria Math` math font ...

Comment: @juanuni - You should mention this issue (and be specific about the nature of the "problem") in your original posting, not in a comment to an answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, It is a problem that appeared on the road ...

Comment: @juanuni If you have a problem with Cambria Math, that's another question.

Comment: @Mico I added no adjustment to the sizes because this is just a proof of concept.

Comment: @Mico is `Scale=MatchLowercase`

Comment: @juanuni -- Sorry. I was typing my earlier comment on an iPhone and didn't notice an "r" was the missing.

Comment: @Mico no problem, I just write for somebody reading your suggestion. Regards.